# How to install arcpy in spyder anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, arcgis, arcpy

I want to install the module arcpy in spyder anaconda. I run the following command in Anaconda Prompt: conda install arcpy -c esri, which follows https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/get-started/installing-arcpy.htm. But it fails. The message shows as below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The python version is 3.7.10. I'm also using ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1.
Does anyone know how to figure this out? Thanks

Comment: You need ArcGIS Pro installed

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Spyder within the ArcGIS Pro conda environment, that is c:\Progra~1\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3

See: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/get-started/using-conda-with-arcgis-pro.htm